# Configuration typescript-eslint in Next.js 13

Tags: next.js, typescript-eslint

I'm developing a Next.js application and I have a ESLint configuration like this,

```
{
  "extends": [
    "next/core-web-vitals",
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"
  ],
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "plugins": ["@typescript-eslint"],
  "root": true
}
```

Note that all the configuration was added for `typescript-eslint` except the `next/core-web-vitals`.

Now, I have a route in app directory which looks like this,

```
import Image from "next/image";

const p = {
  get name() {
    // no returns.
  },
};

export default function Home() {
  p.name;
  return <div></div>;
}
```

In the Visual Studio Code, ESLint will detect an error at line number 4,

`A 'get' accessor must return a value. ts(2378)`.

I believe this came from [eslint:recommended](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/getter-return), and this is what I am expecting.

However, there is no error when I `npm run lint` from the console:

```
$ npm run lint

> next-template@0.1.0 lint
> next lint

✔ No ESLint warnings or errors
```

Any reason why ESLint does not complaint the same error as in the IDE?

Then, I realized that by removing `plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended` from `.eslintrc.json` like this,

```
{
  "extends": ["next/core-web-vitals", "eslint:recommended"],
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "plugins": ["@typescript-eslint"],
  "root": true
}
```

ESLint will be able to detect the same error

```
./app/page.tsx
4:3  Error: Expected to return a value in getter 'name'.  getter-return
```

What is wrong with my `typescript-eslint` configuration? It looks like it overrides the rules of `eslint:recommended`?

Comment: It looks like I need to move `eslint:recommended` to the last:
```
"extends": [
  "next/core-web-vitals",
  "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
  "eslint:recommended"
],
```
then only ESLint will complaint the error when run in the console. However, this is different configuration than what is shown in the typescript-eslint document.

Is this the right configuration?

Answer (score 0):

In '@typescript-eslint', getter functions must always return valid values.

```
/** 1. error: no return */
const p = {
  get name() {
    // no returns.
  },
};
```

```
/** 2. warn: return undefined */
const p = {
  get name() {
    return
  },
};
```

```
/** 3. success */
const p = {
  get name() {
    return 'something'
  },
};
```

If there is no return, modify the eslint:recommended rule. [Rules Page](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/getter-return)

```
{
  "extends": [
    "next/core-web-vitals",
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"
  ],
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "plugins": ["@typescript-eslint"],
  "root": true,
  **"rules": {
    "getter-return": ["error", { "allowImplicit": true }]
  }**
}
```

Comment: The missing return is intentionally to test typescript-eslint integration. My question is, why `npm run lint` does not complaint the error while the IDE does?

I want `npm run lint` to complaint the same error.